# How to do a prefetch_related? Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: python, django

I have these four models/tables:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    position = models.IntegerField()


class CategoryTranslation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name="translated_category",
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Quote(models.Model):
    num_views = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name="quote_category",
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class QuoteTranslation(models.Model):
    quote_text = models.TextField(max_length=512)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    quote = models.ForeignKey(Quote,
                              related_name="translated_quote",
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to prefetch all of the related data, I came up with this:

```py
 t_quote = QuoteTranslation.objects.filter(
        language='en'
    ).prefetch_related(
        'quote__category__translated_category'
    ).first()
```

With this I can get:

```
>>> t_quote.quote_text
>>> t_quote.quote.num_views
>>> t_quote.quote.category.image
```

without any additional query, but I get `None` when I try to get the **`category name`**:

```
>>> t_quote.quote.category.translated_category.name
```

and to get what I want *(the category name)* I still need to do this:

```
>>> t_quote.quote.category.translated_category.get(
      category=t_quote.quote.category.id, language='en').name
```

Am I doing `prefetch_related` wrong? I couldn't figure out how to do it with Prefetch either.

Comment: There can be *multiple* `translated_category`s, not a single one (it is thus a collection), hence `.translated_category.name` does not make much sense.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I get it, the question is *how* to preload the related category name -*the right way*- without the extra query? Doesn't the way I used in the question add a query per records? That is 100 more queries for 100 record!

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing prefetch_related wrong necessarily, it's just that you can't access CategoryTranslation from Category.

This essentially what you're trying to do, which is not valid:

```
cat = Category.objects.filter().first()
cat.translated_category
```

As the Category doesn't have access to CategoryTranslation like that.

To achieve what you are trying to do you need to change your model relationship so that the ForeignKey is on Category and not CategoryTranslation. Otherwise you may just have to pay the cost of an extra lookup.

Comment: Doesn't `prefetch_related` support reverse lookup? Something like this: `Category.objects.prefetch_related('translated_category')`. Also shouldn't the ForeignKey be on the `Many` table in a `OneToMany` relationship?

Comment: Not from what I understand. The only mention of reverse lookup that I can see in the docs is for select_related and that's only for a OneToOneField anyway. In regards to the ForeignKey relationship, I'm not sure how you intend the model to work. I was just saying that the only way you can get that kind of lookup to work is if you swap it

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

# you can add filter() here instead of all() if you want to filter out CategoryTranslation's
# e.g. translated_category_queryset = CategoryTranslation.objects.filter(language='en')
translated_category_queryset = CategoryTranslation.objects.all()

t_quote = QuoteTranslation.objects.filter(language='en'
        ).select_related('quote', 'quote__category'
                         ).prefetch_related(Prefetch('quote__category__translated_category', 
         queryset=translated_category_queryset,
         to_attr='translated_category_instances'))
```

Now, to access data you could do the following. Note none of this will again hit the DB -

```
>>> t_quote.quote_text
>>> t_quote.quote.num_views
>>> t_quote.quote.category.image
```

Now, if you want to access the CategoryTranslation data you could do the following-

```
for translated_category_instance in t_quote.quote.category.translated_category_instances:
    print(translated_category_instance.name)
```

`Note`: This won't hit the DB as long as you are doing basic pythonic operations
over the to_attr `translated_category_instances`.
If you again apply any filter on the CategoryTranslation Table, apply it initially only in the `translated_category_queryset` as mentioned above.

If for e.g. in the near future for any case you can't apply the filter in the initial query than you can apply the filter in the for loop afterwards but don't call the filter() of django. Use python operations as mentioned below -

```
for translated_category_instance in t_quote.quote.category.translated_category_instances:
    if translated_category_instance.language == 'en':
        print(translated_category_instance.name)
```

Look at the docs for `prefetch_related` and `to_attr`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related